# Different sizes of JPEG image in R

Tags: r, jpeg

I am reading a jpeg image (input.jpg) and on writing the same image on disk(as output.jpg), why does its size getting changed. Can i retain the same size.

```
library(jpeg)  
img <- readJPEG('input.jpg')  
file.info('input.jpg')$size

writeJPEG(img,'output.jpg',1)  
file.info('output.jpg')$size 
#is different from input.jpg size
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what's you doing is not reading and writing back the same file. `readJPEG` decodes compressed (lossy) JPEG data into raster array, `writeJPEG` encodes it back again. To get approximately the same size, you should (at least) set `quality` parameter to appropriate value. See `?writeJPEG`:

```
writeJPEG(image, target = raw(), quality = 0.7, bg = "white", color.space)
```

Comment: is there any way to get the quality of the input image?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no formal way for an arbitrary case. Sometimes JPEG quality is stored in the metadata, but it's optional. Try different settings and compare file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of factors that affect the compression:

1. Sampling Rates
2. Quantization table selection
3. Huffman tables (optimal or canned)
4. Progressive or Sequential
   If progressive, the breakdown of the scans.
5. Metadata included

If you do not compress using the same settings as the input, you will get a different size.

You can also get rounding errors in the decompression process that could cause slight differences.